# Material UI Next Theme

Tags: material-design, material-ui

How do I display a radio button with the help of Material UI Next theme? I am working on a project that is made in Material UI Next theme and it is not made in React. It is made in simple HTML templates.

I referred to the https://material-ui-next.com/demos/selection-controls/#radio-buttons official doc about radio buttons but the example given on that page is made using React components. I also tried to inspect the radio buttons element but that does not help because the HTML/CSS is generated by Material UI Next theme automatically.

This is my code (If this is called any code btw :))

```
<input type="radio" />
```

In the same project I am initialising select option by the help of the following function (if that helps):

```
$('select').select();
```

I have tried using variations of the above function for radio buttons but there does not seem to be any initialisation function defined for radio buttons in Material UI Next theme.

```
$('input[type=radio]').radio();
$('input[type=radio]').radiobutton();
$('input[type=radio]').radioBtn();
$('input[type=radio]').radio_button();
```

None of the above is working, and the official doc does not have any function for radio buttons. Please help.

Comment: How are you using Material UI Next theme?  Have you considered using Material Components (from Google): https://material.io/components/web/catalog/input-controls/radio-buttons/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Material UI (Next or otherwise) was designed to be used with React specifically.

Other libraries have implemented the Material design guidelines, and could serve you better than MUI (By just linking a css file).

An example that seems well documented is **Materialize** ([See Radio docs here](http://materializecss.com/radio-buttons.html))

More examples in [this article](https://tutorialzine.com/2016/03/the-15-best-material-design-frameworks-and-libraries).

Comment: The material UI theme is what is used in the project I'm working on. I think you're right about it being used only with React and Materialize being a better alternative but I can't change the base theme library at this stage. Would need to get a good approval for it :) Anyway your answer is helpful. Thanks!